# http page show in https after open it https

Tags: wordpress, https

I created the page in wordpress and set it https by the use wordpress https plugin. I have the problem that when I go to the http page link to the https page it shows in https. I want the rest of the pages should display in http when I go to the https link to http. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in the https plugin,

> "forced the external links"

check this option to display the pages in https only in case user goes to the https to http page. It does't display the http page in https. It displayed the selected pages in https.